# Template literal = undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy empezando a usar *JavaScript/HTML*. Tengo este código y a la hora de cambiar de imprimir la información en consola concatenando *cadena + variable* a usar template literal, pasa de imprimir correcto la información a imprimir `undefined`. Tampoco logro actualizar la información *HTML* desde *JavaScript*. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejemplo DOM con JavaScript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="cabecero">Ejemplo DOM con JavaScript</h1>
    <p id="parrafo">Saludos!</p>
    <script>
      let cabecero = document.getElementById("cabecero").innerHTML;
      console.log("Valor cabecero: " + cabecero);
      let par = document.getElementById("parrafo").innerHTML;
      console.log(`Valor parrafo: ${par.innerHTML}`);
      par.innerHTML = "Nuevo contenido parrafo";
      cabecero.innerHTML = "Nuevo cabecero";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que al definir **cabecero** y **par** estás definiendo el **innerHTML** en lugar del elemento.
Deberías quitar el `.innerHTML` al capturarlos, luego al mostrar sus valores en los **console.log** si agregarle el **.innerHTML** y finalmente hacer el cambio de su contenido.

**Ejemplos para entender la diferencia:**

```
//Esto captura el contenido
 let cabecero = document.getElementById("cabecero").innerHTML;

//Esto captura el elemento que es lo ideal en este caso
 let cabecero = document.getElementById("cabecero");
```

**Finalmente se puede hacer algo como:**

```
console.log(cabecero.innerHTML) //Muestra el contenido en consola

cabecero.innerHTML = "nuevo valor" //Cambia el contenido.
```

---

**El código completo quedaría así:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Ejemplo DOM con JavaScript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 id="cabecero">Ejemplo DOM con JavaScript</h1>
      <p id="parrafo">Saludos!</p>

      <script>
        let cabecero = document.getElementById("cabecero");
        console.log("Valor cabecero: " + cabecero.innerHTML);
        let par = document.getElementById("parrafo");
        console.log(`Valor parrafo: ${par.innerHTML}`);
        par.innerHTML = "Nuevo contenido parrafo";
        cabecero.innerHTML = "Nuevo cabecero";
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
</html>
```